# My USB 3 HUB reigster some USB 3 devices as USB 2.1 but if but the device directly to Motherboard it says 3.0

Tags: usb, usb-3, amd-ryzen

I have an ASUS crosshair hero x790e motherboard, with AM 5 a 7950x. Latest bios, chipsetdrivers etc...
Latest Win 11.

I have only USB 3 ports on the motherboard. I also have an industrial 10 USB 3 HUB from Startech with extra power connected to it.

When I connect my Hedset dongle to the USB HUB it always gets USB 2 (USBView).
And the headset range is crap. When I take the very same dongle and cable and put it in a free motherboard slot it says 3 as intended. But always whatever port I put it on the HUB it gets 2 USB Tree View shows that my HUB has an AMD USB 3.20 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10. But it also has a port 9 that says Generic USB 2 hub. And on that hub, the headset always appears. When in the Hub. I also have a Elgato Camlink 4 connected to the HUB that one I get on port 4 that says Generic SuperSpeed USB 3 Hub. So at least one device gets 3 on my USB 3 HUB.

I also have Elgato Wave XLR same as that one. Adds to the 2 Hub on USB tree view on my USB 3 hardware hub. If I set the same USB cable that I use for my Wave XLR directly to the motherboard it says 3 as it should be.

I have tested different cables from Motherboard to the Hardware Hub but no differences. Different ports on the motherboard have no differences. Uninstalled all the USB controllers no differences.

Tested to just add the headset to the Hardware HUB is still say 2

I do not understand this.

What I expect is that the very same cable on the motherboard or in the hub shall be USB 3
So I can't understand why it's ger downgraded in the Hub. The company support on Startech did not understand either.

So I try to see if there is any super pro here that might know :)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyLLy.png]

Here is what it looks like when on my USB 3.0 hardware hub.
Cam Link is on the HUB says 3 The headset on the hub says 2

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/miOTR.png]

Here I have the headset with the same cable I use on the Hub on the motherboard. And it gets identified as 3 The same happens if I do the same with my Wave XLR.

Comment: It's the first time that I even heard of USB *2.1*. Does this software you use shows the bus speed (e.g. *480Mbps*) somewhere for this problematic "hub" / device? Could it be just some kind of wrong label / name hardcoded in the firmware?

Comment: No, the problem I get is that when the headset is in the Hub and gets the USB 2 the range of the wireless radio gets down to 5m, not the expected 15m. But when on USB 3 registered hub I get 15m radios.  So it does not say wrong related to 2USB 2 or 3. About the speed, I haven't checked. But I think that does not matter here because of the test with my Headset.

Comment: USB 3.2 Gen 1 is equivalent to USB 3.0, your motherboard, does not support USB 3.2 Gen 2 which means it only supports USB 3.0. “ASUS x790e” isn’t a motherboard model, we need more specific information, I wasn’t able to find a single search results for that partial model number

Comment: @Ramhound the OP isn't asking anything about Gen2 / 10Gbps though.

Comment: Author doesn’t seem to be aware their motherboard only supports USB 3.0, suspect that “3.10” is not “USB 3.10” but a numerical identifier that USBView is using. I am also  fairly certain it’s not USBViwew but USBView

Comment: @Jnormen I just realized that the device in concern *itself* appears to be a USB 2.0 device anyway, since even when it is connected directly to the motherboard, the icon shows `H` (which stands for High Speed / 480Mbps) instead of `S` (which stands for SuperSpeed / 5Gbps), while your camera itself appears to be a USB 3.x device. I don't know if this audio dongle's "range" can actually be affected by e.g. how much power the port can supply, but now this seems to be a XY-problem and the "range issue" is likely merely a result of USB 3.0 2.4GHz interference.

Comment: In case you think I'm trolling or if you are interested in the details, here's [pdf](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/327216.pdf) for your information.

Comment: @TomYan don't think you are trolling :) all answers is better than my noob knowledge in this area. I will check more into this. Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound No Im no hardware dude :D so you are 100% right, if I was I would never be asking this question at all. :) And yes I misspelled the tool. Thanks for your support and point out text issues  :)

Comment: I notice the first 5 ports are marked S (superspeed, USB 3) and the rest are marked H (highspeed, USB 2) even when there is nothing plugged in. Have you tried the different ports on the motherboard? And when your USB hub is plugged into your motherboard, it's not one of the superspeed ports.

Comment: how is the hub connected to the motherboard? does it have a USB 3 cable? USB 3 requires 4 extra pins in a different type of connector; if you use a USB 2 cable you can't get USB 3 speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I connect my Hedset dongle to the USB HUB it always gets USB 2
> (USBView). And the headset range is crap.

> When I take the very same dongle and cable and put it in a free motherboard slot it says 3 as intended. [...I get 15m radios]

Your Audeze device is a HS USB2 device. No matter which port you plug it in (root port on MB, or into your HUB), it will connect in USB2 HS mode. Your screenshots provide an evidence for this. The MB connection says "H", and it is irrelevant that the root hub is labelled as "3", and hub connection shows also as "H". So there is no difference.

Now, per your comment, your **actual** problem is that the wireless range is different, it is good (15m) when you plug your Audeze device into MB, and bad (5m) if you plug it into your external hub.

The likely problem is in the difference of electrical implementation of USB ports on ASUS mainboard versus some no-name "industrial 10" hub. There is a known issue that most common wireless devices (2.4GHz) suffer an interference problem with the main USB3 signal frequency (2.5GHz). Your first screenshot shows a bunch of USB3 hubs and Super-Speed devices connected, so it is likely that the interference may be in place.

The problems of electromagnetic interference are difficult to solve, and they are typically come from cheap implementation of board layouts. So it is unlikely that you can solve this, other than replace your hub with a different one.

Alternatively you can try to put a USB2 extender between the hub and the Audeze dongle. However if the problem of parasitic USB3 emission comes from poor ground/shield connections over your tree of hubs, then it might not help.

Comment: The new info after some testing is this: 
When plugged in to USB 3 on my mother board it does not work well. 
If plugged in to the USB 3 Hub it does not work well. The Hub has external power supply. 

What I notice was that why it one time worked on my motherboard was because my cable I used to extend the USB port was a 2.0 cable. So I tested the hub with the USB 2 cable, it works, on mother board it works. But it does not work with Dongle on USB 3 port directly or with a USB 3 extension cable, or USB 3 hub. Tested with a USB 2 hub on my USB Hub and dongle worked that way to.

Answer (score 5):

USB hubs can work in two ways to support various USB standards. Some hubs present several logical hubs to handle several standards. This is what you see in the first screenshot. These logical hubs are so-called “companion hubs”. You can see this information in the text view in UsbTreeView. It can even tell which logical ports belong to the same physical port.

Other hubs do not need this separation at all or only for some standards, combining others. This is what you see in the second screenshot.

As Tom Yan has already correctly identified, the device is a High-speed USB device. You can again find this information in the text view, in addition to the icon. Other types are F for Full-speed and L for Low-speed. This is also the actual speed of the connection and as such what you should be looking at.

Also, with the summary, you can tell whether the device is possibly limited by the USB hub:

```
      ========================== Summary =========================
Vendor ID                : 0x046D (Logitech Inc.)
Product ID               : 0x0AB5
USB Version              : 1.10
Port maximum Speed       : High-Speed (Companion Port 1-4 supports SuperSpeed)
Device maximum Speed     : Full-Speed
Device Connection Speed  : Full-Speed
Self powered             : no
Demanded Current         : 100 mA
Used Endpoints           : 2
```

If “Device maximum Speed” is higher than “Port maximum Speed”, it is probably limited. Note that “Device Connection Speed” could be lowered temporarily to save power.